# API requests Swift UI

Tags: swift, iphone, swiftui

I figured this would be easy, but alas, there appears to have been much change in how this works in swift over the years and I'm only really digging up the old ways around completions.

I've got a chat app & UI driven by an AppState environment object with published variables in it.  I need to make HTTP requests and add the result to my conversation such that the view will show everything appropriately.

All I'm really looking for is a BASIC sample on how to make a POST web request and return the results back in a form where I have the web requests logic in its own function being called from a SEND button.

See below failing attempt which is trying to use completions, however it appears the completions style has stopped being the correct solution somewhere around 2018?  What is the correct way as of today (2023)?

Thanks for tips!

Calling Function:

```
struct MessageInputView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var appState: GlobalAppState
@State var message: ChatMessage = ChatMessage.empty
var body: some View {
            HStack{
                TextField("Your Message", text: $message.message, axis: .vertical)
                    .lineLimit(5)
                Button("Send"){
                    let tmpMsg = message
                    message = ChatMessage.empty
                    //prepare conversation history
                    var history = ""
                    for conversationMessage in appState.conversation.messages
                    {
                        history += ("\n" + conversationMessage.message)
                    }
                    //append current message to the conversation
                    appState.conversation.messages.append(message)
                    
                    //ask openAI, wrapped in task for async
                    doChatRequest(message : tmpMsg, history : history, finished { response, responseError in
                                //append the response from openAI to the conversation
                                appState.conversation.messages.append(response)
                            })
                } //end of SEND.
            }
            .padding()
}
}
```

Function Handling Web Request

```
    func doChatRequest (message: ChatMessage, history : String, finished:     ((response: ChatMessage, responseError: String)) -> Void)
{
    let botActor = ChatActor(name:"bot", isMe: false)

//prepare request
let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:5117/api/v1/OpenAI/chat")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpMethod = "POST"

var botResponse = ChatMessage.empty

let oaiRequest = OpenAIRequest(request: message.message, history: history)
    
do {
    try request.httpBody = JSONEncoder().encode(oaiRequest)
} catch {
    finished(ChatMessage(actor: botActor, date: Date.now, message: "Error converting message into sendable object.") )
}
    
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){ data, response, error in
    if let error = error {
        finished(ChatMessage(actor: botActor, date: Date.now, message: "Error"))
    }
    let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(OpenAIResponse.self, from: data!)
    if let chatResponse = response {
        finished(ChatMessage(actor: botActor, date: Date.now, message: chatResponse.response))
    }
    else
    {
        finished(ChatMessage(actor: botActor, date: Date.now, message: "Error has occurred."))
    }
}
    
task.resume()
}
```

The issue with this code is located here:
[image]

Comment: Basically a SwiftUI View is **not** a view controller, in terms of `UIKit` it's rather a table view cell. Move all the "working code" into a view model. There is no correct way but it's highly recommended to use `async/await` for the asynchronous stuff.

Comment: Watch “Meet async await” from WWDC. It is unclear what the issue is.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this code. What is new is the introduction of Combine publishers and async await that can both serve for your example.

Comment: @Petar the code doesn't actually work though, I've got an error cannot find "finished" in scope.

Comment: try using:
`func doChatRequest(message: ChatMessage, history: String, finished: @escaping (ChatMessage, String) -> Void) {...}`  and call it like this `doChatRequest(message: tmpMsg, history: history) { response, responseError in
 ...}`

Comment: Note, the error you show is because you are missing `:` after `finished`, eg
 `func doChatRequest(message: tmpMsg, history: history, finished: { ....`

Comment: So the code theoretically compiles, but now I get this exception: 2023-07-13 13:51:18.091146-0400 OpenAI_iOS_Starter[25462:2229258] [SwiftUI] Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates

Comment: This is the new calling function layout:                         //ask openAI, wrapped in task for async
                        doChatRequest(message : tmpMsg, history : history) { response, responseError in
                                    //append the response from openAI to the conversation
                                    appState.conversation.messages.append(response)
                                }

Comment: In `doChatRequest(...)`, try using: 
  `DispatchQueue.main.async { appState.conversation.messages.append(response) }`
Take vadian advice and use Swift concurrency framework (async/await) there are hundreds of examples on SO and the net. Also note Apple requires to have `https` unless you have specifically setup your `NSAppTransportSecurity` otherwise in your `Info.plist`.